# ほら and ほれ - the difference

Tags: word-choice

I'm very familiar with ほら, used for urging someone to look at something. But sometimes I hear ほれ in about the same contexts. Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about interjections, then "ほれ" is a variant of "ほら" mainly used by males to mean "look!", "here you are", etc.

Comment: And it sounds quite macho and rough.